# Vuex 3: State is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

versions:

```
"vue": "2.4.2",
"vue-router": "2.7.0",
"vuex": "3.0.1"
```

I am attempting to mock a simple login with two fields that will in the end have JWT to allow an authenticated login.

However, the state in Vuex refuses to change and will output that it is "undefined"

Starting from `Login.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="login" id="login">
    <b-form-input
      id="inputfield"
      v-model="username"
      type="text"
      placeholder="username">
    </b-form-input>
    <b-form-input
      id="inputfield"
      type="password"
      v-model="password"
      placeholder="password">
    </b-form-input>
    <b-button @click="login()" id = "inputfield" variant="outline-success">
      Login
    </b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'login',
    data () {
      return {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      login () {
        this.$store.dispatch('login', {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
          isAuthed: true // this is a temp test to see if it changes
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The store is as such:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    username: null,
    loggedIn: false
  },
  mutations: {
    authUser (state, userData) {
      console.log(userData.isAuthed) // True!
      state.username = userData.username
      state.loggedIn = userData.isAuthed
      console.log(state.loggedIn) // Undefined?
      console.log(state.username) // Also undefined?
    }
  },
  actions: {
    login ({commit}, authData) {
      console.log(authData)
      commit('authUser', {
        authData
      })
  }
})
```

In another words, I can follow the `isAuthed` and `username` around the flow and they're always present, everything goes wrong when trying to assign a new value to the state. Am I doing it wrong? This is following a guide, however vuex is version 3 here, did they change the way you mutate the state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here in your `login` action.

```
commit('authUser', {
  authData
})
```

That should just be

```
  commit('authUser', authData)
```

In the original statement you are creating a new object with an `authData` property. What you want to do is simply pass the `authData` object to the mutation.

Here is [a demonstration](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/POeMpY?editors=0010) of it working.

Comment: It works, thanks. Now my component won't update when the store changes, though, in a `v-if` which is weird.. since it logs the change in state.  but that's another issue